# Modificar datos con colores

Tags: r

Tengo unos datos en excel con formato, algunos números tienen colores etc.
Quiero borrar algunas filas y columnas, pero si lo cargo en R, borro y luego guardo se pierden los colores.

Había pensado en cargar el excel con `loadWorkbook` pero no veo como borrar filas o columnas.

Puedo borrar celdas, como por ejemplo

```
deleteData(wkbook , sheet = 1,cols = 2, rows = 1:5, gridExpand = T)
```

Esto borraría del excel llamado "wkbook" de la columna 2, la celdas del 1 al 5. Pero la columna se mantiene. Lo que quiero es borrar la columna al completo

Comment: Hasta dónde conozco, toda la paquetería de R que tiene que ver con lectura de archivos Excel, solo lee datos y no tiene en cuenta los formatos. Hay alguna opciones para eventualmente establecer formatos, pero no para leerlos inicialmente.

Comment: Con loadWorkbook puedo abrir un excel y mantener los colores. El objetivo era ver si se podía eliminar una columna manteniendo el formato. Sabia como eliminar los datos de una columna, pero no la columna en sí. Me dieron una solución aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75662068/delete-a-column-keeping-the-format-of-the-cells/75666670#75666670